# Projection onto kernel, closed form solution

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Given vector $x_0$ and matrix $L$, find $x$ such that $\lVert x-x_0 \rVert$ is minimal and $Lx = 0$.

I think this is equivalent to finding projection of $x_0$ onto kernel of $L$.
Is there a closed form solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if $x$ is such that $\|x - x_0\|$ is minimal subject to the constraint that $Lx = 0$, then $x$ is the projection onto the kernel of $L$ of $x_0$.

The kernel is the orthogonal complement of the row space. So, if $y$ is the projection of $x_0$ onto the row space of $L$, then $x_0 = x_0 - y$. If $L$ has linearly independent rows, then this projection is given by $y = L^T(LL^T)^{-1}L x_0$, so that
$$
x = x_0 - L^T(LL^T)^{-1}L x_0 = (I - L^T(LL^T)^{-1}L)x_0.
$$
If $L$ does not have linearly independent rows, then the projection onto the row space can be computed using the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse). In particular, we have $y = L^+Lx_0$, so that $x = (I - L^+L)x_0$.